# How to sum like zig-zag algorithm

Tags: java, math

Assuming I have 2 data like this:

```
x = 1, and {10,20,30}.
```

I want to sum like this:

```
1 + 10 = 11, 11 + 20 = 31, and 31 + 30 = 61
```

My code.

```
int x = 1;
int[] arr = {10, 20, 30};
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
{
    sum = arr[i] + x;
}
```

I get this:

```
1 + 10 = 11, 1 + 20 = 21, and 1 + 30 = 31 and so on
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: you keep overwriting `sum`, so you throw away the previous iterations' results. `sum = 1; loop ( sum += arr[i] )` is basically what you need.

Comment: Just wondering: could it be that you are absolutely over-complicating things? Why do you put "zig-zag-complexity" onto something that boils down to 1+10+20+30?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize `sum` to `x`, and add the value at `arr[i]` to `sum` and don´t set the `sum` to `arr[i] + x`.

```
int sum = x; // You only want to add x once, so just say the sum is equal to x
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
{
    // You didn´t sum the values up, you just said the sum is equal to your 
    // x value plus the element at arr[i]
    sum += arr[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, i do not have experience how to make algorithm right... you solve my problem is fast, thanks a lot once again.... regards :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this like

```
int[] arr = {10, 20, 30};
int x = 1;
int sum = x;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
{
    sum = sum + arr[i];
}
```

You just have to add new values to previously obtained sum.
So it is like `sum = sum+next_item`

Answer (score 0):

Also Try to use FOR EACH

```
int sum = 0;
for (int no:arr){
    sum += no;
}
```